# Force Windows 7 RDP Clients to use specific connection settings to save bandwidth

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

Is there a way to force users who are connecting to Remote Desktop to use certain settings (like setting a policy on the machine they are connecting to)?  I am trying to save bandwidth on the little pipe coming into our office.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict various settings for RDP connections via Group Policy. As an example, for one customer we set up an OU for those users who were coming in via RDP to limit things such as color depth, maximum screen resolution, visual effects, printer and drive mapping etc.

Comment: Are you setting the group policy on the machine being connected to or connecting from?